# Changing Twitter Username with api

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, bots

I can’t seem to find anything about changing actual user settings with the twitter api. I see ways to change the account “name”, but that is not the same as the username.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API method for doing this. A user will need to use the Twitter website or app settings in order to change screen (user) name.